# convert 1+year midnight time into unix milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime

i am trying to convert current year + 1 midnight date time to unix timestamp.

for that i have tried

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Today;
DateTime yearEnd = new DateTime( currentTime.Year, 1,1,currentTime.Minute,currentTime.Hour,currentTime.Second,DateTimeKind.Local);

yearEnd = yearEnd.AddYears(1);

double t = (yearEnd.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1,0,0,0)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

and above code is returning `1514782800000`  i.e. `Mon Jan 01 2018 05:00:00 UTC` in  and `Mon Jan 01 2018 10:30:00 Local` (india)

what i am expecting is it converts time to `Mon Jan 01 2018 00:00:00`  local time

Answer (score 1):

By default `DateTime` creates `Unspecified` `DateTimeKind`, so using UTC explicitly helps to avoid confusion. I've tried to rewrite in this way

```
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime yearEnd = new DateTime( currentTime.Year, 1,1,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    yearEnd = yearEnd.AddYears(1); // output DateTime has Utc Kind

    var unixTimestamp = (yearEnd.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))).TotalMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine(unixTimestamp);
```

The output is `1514764800000` which converts to `GMT: Monday, 1 January 2018 00:00:00`

**Update:**

In case you need to convert timestamp back to `DateTime` you may use the following:

```
public static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
{
    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp);
    return dtDateTime; // still Utc Kind
}
```

Usage example if you need to convert to other timezone:

```
    TimeZoneInfo infotime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time (Mexico)"); // specify your desired timezone here
    Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(UnixTimeStampToDateTime(unixTimestamp), infotime));
```

Comment: and how to get it in local time ? shall i use the DateTimeKind.Local

Comment: what do you mean by "to get in local time"? unix timestamp is absolute, it doesn't depend on the timezone. Always use UTC when manupulating/converting dates. At the very end convert the date to your desired timezone

Comment: i wanted to set alram based on yearEnd time in my application hence i was asking for local timezone

Comment: @Hunt add local timezone's offset to yearEnd like: yearEnd = yearEnd.AddYears(1).AddHours(-3). 
In such a way Kind will remain UTC, but it will refer to the moment in time when new year happens in your desired timezone

Comment: nagative value in AddHours to convert in localtimezone is not preferable is there any other approach

Comment: @Hunt you can use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc instead

Comment: and then call SpecifyKind to set Utc explicitly again. btw just curious why offset doen't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right you want the following:

```
double result = new DateTime(currentTime.Year + 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
```

Or improved for readablity

```
DateTime newYear = new DateTime(currentTime.Year + 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime uTSBegin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
double result2 = newYear.Subtract(uTSBegin).TotalSeconds;
```